# Сравнение int в mysql

Tags: mysql

Добрый день.
Есть таблица со столбцами

```
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
`c_a` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

Делаю запрос

```
Select * from table where c_a > 0
```

Выводит 0 строк хотя есть данные больше 0. Но если сделать

```
Select * from table where c_a > id.
```

То все правильно показывает.

Где ошибка?

Спасибо.

Comment: это из create  пробовал и 0 и '0'

Comment: `DEFAULT '0'` - по стандарту использовать кавычки. У вас случаем `c_a` и `id` не меньше нуля? Вы что-то упустили, но этого не предоставили. Предоставьте дамп своей таблицы.

Comment: Что показывает `Select MAX(c_a) from table`?

Comment: И где Вы выполняете запросы?

Comment: Select MAX(colvopodpisok_action) from channel выводит 0

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/euiBt9Z83TaEqQ вот ссылка на дамп

Comment: Если MAX = 0, то нет у Вас значений больше 0

Comment: Так мне в запросе и надо выбрать все больше чем 0

Comment: >=  а вот сработало. все понятно. Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Не понимаю, почему запрос `Select * from table where c_a > id` ( `Select * from channel where c_a > id` ) должно что-то выводить, а вы пишите, что выводит. Покажите `Select MIN(id), MAX(id), MIN(c_a), MAX(c_a) from channel`, а то мистика какая-то получается